# Querying MYSQL longtext holding JSON

Tags: mysql, json

I have a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `Event` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `last_updated` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `info` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=720 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I need to query it using the `info` column (which holds JSON string).

If I query it doing:

```
SELECT e.id, e.created, JSON_TYPE(e.info) AS info
  FROM Event e
```

It returns OBJECT on the INFO column, but if I try to grab an specific column of the JSON, I receive:

> SQL Error [3144] [22001]: Data truncation: Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'.

The SQL I am running:

```
SELECT INFO - > '$User'
  FROM (SELECT e.id, e.created, JSON_TYPE(e.info) AS info
          FROM Event e) as X
```

**Its not an option to change the type of the column to json**

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan it was right there in my face! Thanks! I will accept your answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to [CAST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html) to JSON then

```
SELECT info -> '$.User', info_type
  FROM (SELECT e.id, e.created, 
               JSON_TYPE( CAST( info AS JSON ) ) AS info_type, 
               CAST( info AS JSON ) AS info
          FROM Event e) as X
```

since a string value within a JSON value accepting function( `JSON_TYPE()` ) wouldn't work.

*Btw, you don't need to bring the JSON type, but the JSON only, for your case.*

**Update** : You can alternatively use without subquery by using `JSON_EXTRACT()` as

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT( CAST( info AS JSON ) , '$.A' ) AS info,
       JSON_TYPE( CAST( info AS JSON ) ) AS info_type
  FROM Event
```

Comment: I actually just used the cast (without JSON_TYPE)... with JSON_TYPE it was failing

Comment: sure @Walucas , since it does not return a JSON but the type.